# FastCGI with perl - On shared Linux webhost

Tags: linux, apache, perl, .htaccess

I am trying to build an online "live chat" service, and for many reasons I found FastCGI to be suitable for that (as per its documentation), but I cannot seem to get it running.

I am using shared hosting with Apache 2.2 with mod_fcgid installed. 
My .htaccess file has the following line added:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
```

My perl test script named fcgitest.fcgi is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# fcgitest.fcgi

use diagnostics;
use warnings;
use strict;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser'; # tester only!

use FCGI;
my %env; my $in = new IO::Handle; my $out = new IO::Handle; my $err = new IO::Handle; 
my $request=FCGI::Request($in, $out, $err, \%env);
if($request->IsFastCGI()==0) { 
    print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"; binmode STDOUT; print "ERR"; exit 0; 
}
my $tm=time();
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    my $env=$request->GetEnvironment();
    print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"; binmode STDOUT;
    print time()." ".$env;
    if(time()>($tm+60)) { $request->Finish(); exit 0; }
}
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"; binmode STDOUT; print "---"; exit 0;
```

When I call this script from within one of my pages, I getting Internal Server Error, code 500, with NO explanation and NO error log in the server log file.

1. I tried to hide all the code and leave only the print statement, the problem remains the same.
2. I tried moving the file into the fcgi-bin directory, but the problem remains.
3. I have checked that the perl module is well installed.

I have no idea what can cause this error, as my hosting supplier says the server is well-configured for FCGI...

Comment: What happens when you run 'perl -c fcgitest.fcgi' from the command line as the same user as the apache server?

Comment: I have no shell access...

Comment: How are you deploying your own fastcgi handler?

Comment: Why are you putting stdout into binmode to send text/plain?

Answer (score 0):

what shared hosting are you using? Most shared hosting have fcgi already installed, and you don't need to test the fcgi module on your own.

For example, on godaddy shared hosting, .fcgi/.fpl and even my .pl files would run over FCGI instead of normal CGI. No extra effort.

try different file permissions like 644, 700, 750, 755 for the script you are running.

Also, try adding the line:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
```

after use CGI::Carp line.

Comment: I tried this too, it is a bit wired that it is still not working... If permission is not 755, the error.log have contents about it. As for the header, I tried it in the beginning, the result is the same... So wired...

Comment: I think you are missing this, add this on line 2:

use cPanelUserConfig;

Comment: since you are using shared hosting, there should be cpanel or something similar installed. Which one is it? Please check that some control panels... place all the non-core modules separately, and a line similar to above needs to be added to call them.
Please check, which one is needed in your case.

Comment: Yes, I am using cPanel

Comment: You might wanna go to Perl Modules by clicking on its icon inside your cpanel and check what is the path to your Perl Modules, and add that as line 2 in your scripts. Also, make sure that the modules you are calling in your script are installed.. check the list on that page.

Comment: I was thinking.. that since you are on shared hosting, and using Cpanel.. its possible that fcgi was already enabled on the server (check with support). If so, the line Add Handler fcgid-script .fcgi should have been already added to the parent .htaccess file, which is not available to you. But since you added the handler on your child .htaccess file as well. Is it possible that both are going into a conflict?